# How to upgrade Jersey1.18 to 2.x version and Unit test Web Services using latest Jersey test framework

Tags: java, api, unit-testing, rest, jersey

I'm a newbie to Unit testing Rest Webservices. 
In our project, I'm trying to write a simple UT for Rest Services using Jersey test framework. I have upgraded our Jersey(1.18.1) to latest version(2.3.15) by replacing the following jars and using latest versions of Jersey Test Frameworks.

[image]

I'm able to handle almost all the dependencies except this one. When I try to run the test case, I'm getting the following exception :
[image]

Could anybody suggest me what I am missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using Maven. All you need to add is this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And it will pull in all the required jars

[image]

```
public class SimpleJerseyTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("/hello")
    public static class HelloResource {
        @GET
        public String getHello() {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(HelloResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String response = target("hello").request().get(String.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello World", response);
    }
}
```

By the way, 2.3.1 is not the latest version, Jersey just released 2.16. And the dependencies will be a little different from what you see above.

Some resources:

- [Jersey Documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html)
- [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)
- [Some examples from the source code tests](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/test-framework/providers/grizzly2/src/test/java/org/glassfish/jersey/test/grizzly/web)

The above is just for basic support. If you need JSON support, you will need more jars. Or with Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

For multi-part support, you will also need more jars. With Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Both these depedencies require more than just one jar. Here is an image of all the jars for the above three Maven dependencies combined, if you need to manually acquire them. Though I strongly suggest using/learning Maven. It will make life so much easier.

[image]